# Can I Add a custom Delegate to a Custom CALayer

Tags: iphone, ipad, delegates, protocols, calayer

I am trying to add a delegate to a CALayer so I can know when the animation sequence is complete.  It's animating 40 sublayers around the screen.  Once I add the delegate as I do below, all the animation stops on the CALayer.

Here is my code:

```
@protocol NIArticlesLayerDelegate;

@interface NIArticlesLayer : CALayer {
    id<NIArticlesLayerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<NIArticlesLayerDelegate> delegate;

@end



@protocol NIArticlesLayerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)itemAtCenter:(id)item;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [CALayer Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), `CALayer` already has a property called delegate which MUST be assigned to the owning view. Try changing the name?